# C++ primer 5 edition. move iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move-semantics

I am reading C++ primer 5 ed. I'm reading it so carefully because it is really useful. I also practise too much from what I've learned from it. Now I am on chapter 13. move semantics. move iterators. everything is clear until I reached this paragraph:

> It is worth noting that standard library makes no guarantees about which algorithms can be used with move iterators and which cannot. Because moving an object can obliterate the source, you should pass move iterators to algorithms only when you are  confident that the algorithm does not access an element after it has assigned to that  element or passed that element to a user-defined function.

Can someone explain to me this paragraph? I didn't understand "you should pass move iterators to algorithms only when you are  confident that the algorithm does not access an element after it has assigned to that  element or passed that element to a user-defined function."?? which element he is talking about? Thank you guys!

E.G:

```
    std::vector<int> vi{5, 7, 10, 24}, vi2;
        std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(vi)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(vi)), std::back_inserter(vi2));
        std::copy(vi2.cbegin(), vi2.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
```

Does that mean `copy` shouldn't access elements of `vi`?

Comment: _which element_: the element being iterated over.  for example, if you are using a move iterator on a vector, then the element of the vector.  as a result of the move iterator, the element may be destroyed.

Comment: @jdigital: you mean the move iterator passed in to the algorithm?

Comment: yes, does that make sense to you?  using the move iterator may result in the destruction of the elements you're iterating over.

Comment: @jdigital: yes. I find it a bit confusing. would yoy mind to explain with an example?

Comment: check out this explanation, it comes with drawings ;-) https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/25/move-iterators/

Comment: @jdigital: I've edited the topic.